# UnboundLocalError when returning a variable

Tags: python, static-methods

I have a static method that collects some things together and returns them.

```
@staticmethod
def testForMetrics(....):
    ...
    ...

    coverages = Metrics.findCoverageStats(....)

    ...
    return coverages, ....
```

findCoverageStats looks like

```
@staticmethod
def findCoverageStats(....)
    coverages = {}

    ...# fill coverages with calculations

    return coverages
```

Running tells me `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'coverages' referenced before assignment`, but only in very rare cases.

What sort of edge cases could cause cause this behavior?

Comment: Which function does the error appear in?

Comment: A stack trace would help....

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `coverages` variable initialization in an `if` clause inside the function? Or `del coverages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of error you refer to (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xxx' referenced before assignment`) is typical to the situations when due to multiple potential paths of execution through a function a variable is not set.

See below for a (simplified) example of a such a situation:

```
def fun():
    if random.randint() < 1000:
        xxx = 1
    else:
        yyy = 1

    return xxx
```

A way out would be to declare `xxx` with a default value or assign in the  `else`  clause as well (the first solution below).

```
def fun():
    xxx = 0
    if random.randint() < 1000:
        xxx = 1
    else:
        yyy = 1

    return xxx
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Upon closer inspection of the code above the call to findCoverageStats I see there is an if condition: continue construction. That'll do it.

Comment: Good to know. Could you then please accept the answer?